# ein + ipython non-responsive with python 'raw_input'

Tags: python, ipython, ein

I am using Emacs with the `ein` package to edit ipython files. Everything works fine except when I have a line like:

```
fhandle = raw_input('enter your file name: ')
```

to prompt for a file name. The ipython subprocess that is running inside Emacs stops responding. (there is a little star at `In[]` that indicates this).

When I run the same command in the usual jupyter notebook web interface it works fine as usual. (there is a little box where it prompts me for the file name). I am thinking emacs + ein somehow doesn't have this capability?. What am I doing wrong here?. I am using python 2.7.

Comment: I am not using `ein` but I have the same behaviour. Have have you solved?

Answer (score 1):

I am using emacs 25.2

In my case I tink that this was the problem
`https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8797`

I solved setting up Python 3 and installing `python-mode`.

Note that in Python 3 `raw_input` has been replaced by `input`.